# Increment ID number in case of merging tables (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to merge two tables - SomeTable_1 and SomeTable_2. They have the same columns and come from different DBs (SomeDB_1/SomeDB_2).

So I'm starting with blank table (SomeTable) in another DB (SomeDB) and starting to merge data from above mentioned tables.

```
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] SELECT * FROM [SomeDB_1].[dbo].[SomeTable_1];
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] SELECT * FROM [SomeDB_2].[dbo].[SomeTable_2];
```

Everything works fine but table logic is based on ID (primary key) and when I merge two tables according to described above, I'm getting two duplicate records (with the same ID). Is there any way how to handle this issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you add a new column in [SomeTable] to specify from where the data came? Do you need the original ids? If not, can you substitute the original ids, for a new identity column?

Comment: Yes, I need original IDs.

Comment: Then I see no other solution than adding an additional column in [SomeTable]

Answer (score 1):

Tou can do this way :

Instead of using * you can set the the column name avoiding the id column ..

```
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] (column1, column2, column3...)  SELECT  column1, column2, column3 , ... FROM [SomeDB_1].[dbo].[SomeTable_1];
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable]  (column1, column2, column3...) SELECT column1, column2, column3 , ...FROM [SomeDB_2].[dbo].[SomeTable_2];
```

Be certain that you make the id column in `SomeTable` set to autoincrement.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was also wondering about. But I need to keep ID for further inner join...

Comment: Then you must add a  column related to source table name .. and use a composite key get the proper row

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the below code. It will allow to insert data to the **IDENTITY COLUMN**. This is working fine with SQL Server 2012

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] ON
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] SELECT * FROM [SomeDB_1].[dbo].[SomeTable_1];
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] SELECT * FROM [SomeDB_2].[dbo].[SomeTable_2];
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] OFF
```